# Looping through multiple SQL querys?

Tags: php, sql, loops

I want to loop through my database and only handle 100 rows and on time otherwise my RAM would get exhausted.

But my problem is, I do not know, why my script isn't increase the start and end limit. So I only get one return and do not loop through my database by increasing the start and end limit by +100.

Does anyone see my failure?

```
$count_values = mysqli_num_rows($values_gk);
$count_values = intval($count_values);
$myfile = fopen("httpdocs/wp_all_import.txt", "a");

if($values_gk === FALSE){
    fwrite($myfile, "SQL Error\n");
}

$start = -100;
$end = 0;

do{
$start = $start + 100;
$end = $end + 100;

if($end > $count_values){
    $end = $count_values;
}

$values_gkw = $database_gk->query("SELECT `ID` FROM `fWR6qIN_posts` where post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish' limit $start, $end");

fwrite($myfile, "Entered 1. While Loop\n");

while($row = $values_gkw->fetch_assoc()){

    if($row["ID"] != null){
        //do something with the values
        //code removed to reduce the text here
    }
}

fwrite($myfile, "\n+++ Start: " .$start. " Limit: " .$end. " +++\n\n");

} while ($end <= $count_values);
```

Count Value: (Check without limit to get the amount of all rows)

```
$values_gk = $database_gk->query("SELECT `ID` FROM `fWR6qIN_posts` where post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish'");
$count_values = mysqli_num_rows($values_gk);
$count_values = intval($count_values);
```

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: "only handle 100 rows and on time otherwise my RAM would get exhausted" . . . Do tell more.  This isn't 1980.

Comment: This code seems fine. What value stores `$count_values`?

Comment: You are going to get a problem if `$end > $count_value`. Then you set `$end` equals to `$count_value`. But your do-while loop while `$end <= $count_values`. Which is true since you set them equals.
**You will get an infinit loop** !

Comment: Actual I do not get an infinity loop. The script just determinate after the first loop... But I do not get why... where is my error?

Comment: Then you need to check the value of `$count_values`. Cause if it's a good one, you should get an infinit loop.

Comment: $count_values is 2027. I updated the question with the query for the value!

Comment: Does somebody know where my error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Limit syntax is `LIMIT offset, count` NOT `LIMIT offset_start, offset_end`.
It will select `100` rows in first iteration of loop but will select `200` rows in second iteration of loop as `$end` = 200 in second iteration and 300 rows in third iteration and so on.

And as specified by kalrodan your code generates infinite loop.

I made several corrections in code. Try this :

```
$start = -100;
$limit = 100;//constant never changes
$count = 0;
do{
    $start = $start + 100;
    $count = $count + 100;//see changes here

    if($count > $count_values){//see changes here
        $limit = $count_values - $start;//see changes here
    }

    $values_gkw = $database_gk->query("SELECT `ID` FROM `fWR6qIN_posts` where post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish' limit $start, $limit");//$start, $limit here

    fwrite($myfile, "Entered 1. While Loop\n");

    while($row = $values_gkw->fetch_assoc()){

        if($row["ID"] != null){
            //do something with the values
            //code removed to reduce the text here
        }
    }

    fwrite($myfile, "\n+++ Start: " .$start. " Limit: " .$end. " +++\n\n");

} while ($count < $count_values);//condition change here too
```

Comment: I still end up in a infinity loop. He just continues but of course, there is nothing to select. But I do not get the failure?

Comment: @ThisIsDon I tested this exact code on local db and it works just fine. Just a little warning I get is that `$end` is not defined at `fwrite` line because I removed `$end` but forgot to remove it from `fwrite` line. And Make sure you are using exact same code, do not forget to change the `do-while` loop condition too. I made corrections at many places so just copy paste whole code and try.